# Adobe Acrobat Pro - How to show or hide pages based on a value selected from a dropdown field

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am working with a pdf form that contains several versions of a disclaimer that shows or hides based on a value selected in a dropdown field. I have seen this done on a pdf put together by a third party, but I am not sure how they did it.

For example: Page 1 has the form with the state drop down. Pages 2-5 is the first version of the disclaimer, and pages 6-10 is the second version of the disclaimer. If, say, Georgia is selected in the dropdown, page 2-5 is visible and 6-10 is hidden. If Florida is selected, vice versa.

I know how to show/hide other fields based on a dropdown selection, but have not yet found a way to show/hide pages.

I am using a Creative Cloud account which includes Acrobat Pro. Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it can be accomplished. There are two methods. If the disclaimer pages vary in length, You need to set up the pages that you want to show/hide as named "templates". Template pages can then be hidden and shown as needed. It's easier if the disclaimer is always the same number of pages. In that case, you can use layers over blank pages. The layer for a particular disclaimer can then be hidden or shown.